# (non-trivial) isotrivial family of elliptic curves over C^{\times}

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

So How does one prove (rigorously) that
$$
Frac(\mathbb{C}[x,y,t]/(y^2-x^3-t)) \not\simeq Frac(\mathbb{C}[t][x,y]/(y^2-x^3-1))?
$$
So here $Frac$ denotes the fraction field of an integral domain.

Note that this gives an example of (a non-trivial) isotrivial family over $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a slightly different proof which works over any field $k$ (of characteristic different from 2 and 3). The first field is just $k(x,y)$. As Rita indicated, if it is isomorphic to the second field as $k$-extension, than there exists a birational map $f: \mathbb P^2\to \mathbb P^1\times E$. This birational map induces a birational map over the algebraic closure of $k$, so we can suppose $k$ is algebraically closed. Composing with the projection to $E$, we get a dominant rational map $g: \mathbb P^2\to E$. By two arbitrary points where $g$ is defined, it passes a line $L$. As $E$ is not rational, by Lüroth $g|_L$ is constant. So $g$ is constant, contradiction. More quickly, one can say that the existence of $g$ implies that $E$ is unirational and this is impossible.

**EDIT**: the rational map $\mathbb P^2\to E$ is not birational ! but dominant.

Comment: This is not so much different as it looks from the proof I gave. $h^1({\mathcal O})$ is the dimension of the Albanese variety, that for the non rational surface is precisely $E$. Now your argument  shows precisely that the Albanese variety of a unirational variety is $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Qing for the very slick argument! It is completely self contained and the key result that you use is that there is no non-constant rational map going form  $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow E$ which as you pointed is a consequence of Luroth's theorem. Cool! 

Comment: Still, you need to know that $E$ is not rational...
The only way I know to show that is by computing the genus. 

Comment: To show that $E$ is not rational, one can aslo compute directly $H^0(E, O_E(\infty))$ which is equal to $k$, and would be of dimension $2$ over $k$ if $E$ was rational. 

Comment: To prove that $\mathbb P^1\times E$ is not rational, one can also use the fact that its $\pi_1$ is obviously non-trivial. 

Comment: I was just trying to point out that all arguments seem to boil down to showing that $h^1({\mathcal O})>0$ (equivalently, $h^0(\Omega^1)>0$). For instance, to use the fundamental group you need to know that it is birational invariant for surfaces, which is true but not easier to prove than the birational invariance of $h^1({\mathcal O})$. Indeed,$h^1({\mathcal O})$  is one half of the first Betti number, hence a rougher invariant than $\pi_1$.

Answer (score 19):

The second field is the function field of $X_2:=E\times {\mathbb P}^1$, where $E$ is a smooth elliptic curve; the first one is the function field of $X_1:=\{zy^2-x^3-tz^2=0\}\subset {\mathbb P}^3$. The surface $X_1$ is rational, as one can see by projecting onto ${\mathbb P}^2$ from the point $P$ given by $x=y=z=0$, which is a double point of $X_1$. The surface $X_2$ is not rational, since it has $h^1({\mathcal O}_{X_2})=1$. So $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not birational, and the two  fields are not  isomorphic (as extensions of $\mathbb C$).

Comment: So I guess the first $X_2$ should read as $X_1$. Is it completely obvious that $h^1(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a birational invariant? After all
$\mathcal{O}_X$ is the sheaf of regular functions on $X$ which a priori could change under birational maps.

Comment: @Georges: I've edited and fixed the typos (I hope). Thanks!

@Hugo: $h^1({\mathcal O})$ is a birational invariant because by Hodge theory it is equal to $h^0(\Omega^1)

Comment: @Hugo (continued): there is also a famous rationality criterion by Castelnuovo, that says that a surface $S$ is rational iff $h^1({\mathcal O})=h^0(2K_S)=0$.

Comment: I'm quite happy with your proof but I think there should be a more 
elementary proof which is self contained. You see the whole point of 
this question is to come up with a birational invariant and if we 
assume from the outset that $h^1(\mathcal{O})$ is a birational 
invariant then it (almost) kills the problem. 

Comment:  Of course, one could 
verify by a local computation that a blow up at one point does 
not change $h^1(\mathcal{O})$ but then one would have to show that 
a birational map between $X_1$ and $X_2$ could be obtained by a 
sequence of blow ups which a priori looks as a more difficult 
question than the original. 

Comment: The last statement is a well known fact, have a look at Beauville's  book on surfaces, the chapter on birational maps of surfaces.

Comment: Maybe Hugo was looking for a completely elementary and self contained proof.